# Add breaks even when they don't exist

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several charts that I have made in R. I noticed that when I filter the data into different categories, I get slightly different breaks. I'd like to have the same breaks on every chart, even if those breaks don't exist within that category. Is it possible to add breaks that might not even exist within any given category? I've even tried adding the breaks in the code below, but as you can see in the charts, none of the breaks match between any of the 3 categories.

```
yx %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select( Cat, y, x, z ) %>% 
  filter( Cat == "A" ) %>% 
  ggplot(.) +
  ggtitle("A") +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  geom_contour_filled( aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
                       breaks = seq(250,310,5))

yx %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select( Cat, y, x, z ) %>% 
  filter( Cat == "B" ) %>% 
  ggplot(.) +
  ggtitle("B") +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  geom_contour_filled( aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
                       breaks = seq(250,310,5))

yx %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select( Cat, y, x, z ) %>% 
  filter( Cat == "C" ) %>% 
  ggplot(.) +
  ggtitle("C") +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  geom_contour_filled( aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
                       breaks = seq(250,310,5))
```

[image: A]

[image: B]

[image: C]

Comment: You have to set the same `limits` in each plot. breaks outside of the limits won't show up.

Comment: Limits isn't a known parameter for contours. `Ignoring unknown parameters: limits`

Comment: Sorry. My fault. Had `scale_fill_xxx` in mind.